# How to use apache-status if the http connection table is full?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I am currently faced with a comical situation: I am testing DOS tools against a test server, and I cannot monitor the server with the http status scoreboard, as all connection threads are used up!

Is there any other way to monitor the connection table without the use of this plugin?

Comment: Look at netstat?

Answer (score 2):

You should not ask the software you're trying to crash to provide you with useful statistics. Try to monitor it using other tools like ps, netstat, collecting packets, etc.

To access the scoreboard you'll need at least 1 thread/process left in the pool to process your requests. Try to set your "DoS" tool to limit itself to ($apache_threads - 1) connections but that wouldn't be much of a DoS test, would it?